# Идеальный парсер

Tags: алгоритм, парсер

Возник вопрос в плане архитектуры: каким должен быть парсер - запускаться с сервера или все-таки из браузера (при этом он будет написан на JS).

P.S. Вопрос возник из-за удивления коллег по поводу того, что написанный мной парсер запускается из браузера, при этом сам я backend-программист.

Comment: парсер чего? кто его _должен_ запускать? кто его запускает на самом деле? куда он _должен_ отдавать результаты? куда он _отдает_ результаты?

Comment: Наверное, все зависит от того какие задачи он должен выполнять

Comment: Брать данные со стороннего ресурса из DOM-дерева, например.

Comment: @Grundy, отдавать результаты на сервер.

Comment: Если время работы такого парсера больше, чем пользователь может ждать, то определенно он должен отрабатывать на сервере, а не в браузере.

Comment: что значит _запускается из браузера_?

Comment: А почему такой скудный набор вариантов? Парсер можно еще запускать из консоли. или с помощью cron. А то и вовсе  отослав смс на номер (писал я такое разок)

Comment: @Grundy, открываешь страницу, на которой его код, - и скрипт выполняется, отдавая результаты.

Comment: то есть он делает ajax запрос на сторонний сервер, разбирает ответ и результат отправляет на сервер? А разве он не свалится из-за CORS? или сторонний сервер тоже ваш?

Comment: @Grundy, пропускал обращение к url через https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com.

Comment: То есть вместо одного запроса к нужному сайту, получается два запроса: первый к прокси, второй - от прокси к сайту. Этого можно было избежать, делая запрос напрямую со своего сервера

Comment: @Grundy, это же не единственный минус такого подхода? В каких случаях писать парсеры на JS имеет смысл?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, все зависит от назначения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идеальный парсер может быть написан на любом языке.

Представим две ситуации:

1. Мгновенное единовременное получение данных со стороннего ресурса
Допустим, пользователь вставил в сообщение ссылку на картинку. Логично на клиентской же стороне скачать эту картику и отобразить в том же самом сообщении, а на сервер передать уже base64, например.

2. Выкачивание сферического коня в ваккуме
Допустим, нужно собрать неограниченное количество информации для одной задачи. В этом случае я бы создал очередь в RabbitMQ и складывал туда список заданий. Список заданий можно формировать на клиентской стороне.
Далее очередь могут разбирать несколько скриптов, которые будут скачивать и парсить данные. Совершенно не важно, на каком языке они написаны. Да пусть это будет даже клиентский js пользователя вашего личного бложика :) Главное, что бы это было эффективно. Избегайте ситуаций, когда пользователь может закрыть браузер через 98 часов парсинга за секунду до успешного завершения :)

Comment: Кстати, вариант с парсингом через клиентский js посетителя может заменить списки прокси. <s>злобный смех</s>

Comment: Видимо, тогда имеет смысл сразу передать нужные значения для парсинга на сервер и реализовать парсер на нем, а на выходе таки получить значения подсчетов, верно? Это и будет лучшим вариантов для парсинга большого DOM-дерева, где входящее значение одно - название раздела?

Comment: Если получение этого DOM дерева не занимает много времени, то вполне вероятно.

Comment: а если много, и данные все равно нужно вернуть? Как поступать в таком случае?

Comment: Если получение данных + парсинг > 20 секунд, я бы не стал делать это в браузере.